# Three.js raycaster.intersectObjects got wrong results

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to detect collision using raycaster as described in the example "collision detection" of http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/, but cannot get the correct results. My codes are like follows:

```js
                var material_blue = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    color: 0x0000ff,
                    specular: 0x000000,
                    shininess: 10
                });                              

                var dest_pos = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 3);

                cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2), material_blue);
                cube.position.set(dest_pos.x, dest_pos.y, dest_pos.z);
                scene.add(cube);

                var collidableMeshList = []
                collidableMeshList.push(cube)

                var orig_pos = new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, -1);

                let dir = dest_pos.clone();
                dir.sub(orig_pos);
                console.log("dir: " + dir.x + ", " + dir.y + ", " + dir.z)

                let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(orig_pos, dir.clone().normalize());

                let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(collidableMeshList);
                console.log(intersects);
                console.log("intersects.length = " + intersects.length);
                if (intersects.length > 0)  {
                    console.log("intersects[0].point: (" +  intersects[0].point.x + ", " +  intersects[0].point.y + ", " +  intersects[0].point.z + ")") 
                }
```

In my codes, I put a cube of size (2, 2, 2) at dest_pos (0, 0, 3), and send a ray from orig_pos (0.5, 0.5, -1). In theory, I should get a hit at (0.5, 0.5, 2), but at the end, what I got is (0.5, 0.5, -1), which is exactly the orig_pos. I tried to solve the problem with different ways suggested on stackoverflow, but all failed to get the correct results. 
Any suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for including a snippet. Would you be able to convert it into a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Being able to actually run it would greatly help our ability to debug and assist you.

Comment: You should also include links to the questions/answers you have already tried, and some details on why they don't work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! This is my first time to post a questions on stackoverflow and I am still learning the correct way to ask a good question. I will improve my question in the future.

Comment: I found the question is helpful for me：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271549/please-explain-three-js-raycaster-direction-parameter. The reason for the wrong result is "I needed to make sure the meshes was rendered so that worl matrixes was applied"